# Yii2 migration - add column after other one

Tags: yii2

I want to add a new column through migration in Yii2, using this code:

```
public function up()
{
    $this->addColumn('news', 'priority', $this->integer());
}

public function down()
{
    $this->dropColumn('news', 'priority');
}
```

And it works but I want it to be second column, after name.

It is possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, can you try this:

```
$this->addColumn('news', 'priority', 'integer AFTER `name`');
```

Answer (score 4):

Since v2.0.8 you can also do the following:

```
$this->addColumn('news', 'priority', $this->integer()->after('name'));
```

See https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/2.0.8/framework/db/ColumnSchemaBuilder.php#L209